# How does rails know when a cookie is expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, session

I'm using cookie_store to store my user session:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_session', expire_after: 1.month
```

I trust that this does what the library says...but when I decrypted an actual cookie from production, I found

```
"{"session_id":"42193dc27a12fca399509e6b6bb29751","_csrf_token":"EIqxBDqpUX1Bxmig1WXekbCExnhq4LP5D1JDYfoI8tA","app_field1": ...}"
```

(don't worry this cookie is from over a month ago so it's not a security risk to leak it)

Obviously rails set `session_id` and `_csrf_token`. But none of these are timestamps. How does rails know when this cookie should expire? Does session_id actually get decoded into a timestamp?

It's important to me that these cookies do expire because I'm wary of session replay attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `Set-Cookie` header:

```bash
#                                                     vvvvvvv
Set-Cookie: _stackoverflow_session=u9O...%3D; path=/; expires=Fri, 29 Mar 2024 06:12:25 GMT; httponly; SameSite=Lax
#                                  ^^^^^^^^^
#                 you've decrypted this part
```

You can inspect session options to see the current configuration:

```
session.options[:expire_after] #=> 1 month
```

This option is actually only [used](https://github.com/rack/rack-session/blob/v2.0.0/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb#L401) by the `Rack::Session` to create the appropriate `Set-Cookie` header. All this happens in middleware, so the easy way to see the result is to inspect cookies or the actual header in your browser.

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#expiresdate*

Comment: Thank you, I just suspected it. Sigh this means my cookies can be replayed infinitely.

Comment: if it is that important there are ways to handle it https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-expiry